# System with cubed and squared terms

Tags: contest-math

Find the ordered pair (x,y) such that

$x + y ^3 = 100$

$x^2 - y^2 = 100$

I decided to substitute $x = 100 - y^3$ into the second equation and got

$10000 - 200y^3 + y^6 - y^2 = 100$

Is there any trick or method I can use to solve the 6th degree polynomial above? Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2By%5E3%3D100%2C+x%5E2-y%5E2%3D100) finds two real and four complex solutions.  None are given exactly, so it probably used a numeric solution.

Answer (score 1):

Beside numerical methods, you could "easily" *estimate* the solutions.

Consider that you look for the zero's of function
$$f(y)=y^6-200 y^3-y^2+9900$$ for which
$$f'(y)=2 y \left(3 y^4-300 y-1\right)$$ If you neglect the $-1$, you have a solution which is "close" to $y=10^{2/3}$.

Make a series expansion of $f(y)$ around this value
$$f(y)=-10 \left(10+10^{1/3}\right)-2\ 10^{2/3} \left(y-10^{2/3}\right)+\left(900\
   10^{2/3}-1\right) \left(y-10^{2/3}\right)^2+O\left(\left(y-10^{2/3}\right)^3\right)$$ which is a quadratic in $\left(y-10^{2/3}\right)$. Solve it to get
$$y_\pm=10^{2/3}+\frac{10^{2/3}\pm 10 \sqrt{899+900\ 10^{2/3}}}{900\ 10^{2/3}-1}$$ which gives $y_-\sim 4.4721$ and $y_+\sim 4.8133$ while the exact solution would be $4.4656$ and $4.8073$.